# ModuleNotFoundError while running pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to Python-Flask environment. On my project, I have an Flask API project, inside which I have created few unittests. API is working as expected using POSTMAN or with any API client, but I am trying to run unit tests using "pytest" command, its giving me errors on my unit test(s) like " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <name of pip package". This happens only for few packages like "flask_expects_json", "redis" etc. My conftest.py looks like this.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app():
    """Return a session-wide application configured in TEST mode."""
    _app = create_app()
    return _app
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def app_request():
    """Return a session-wide application configured in TEST mode."""
    _app = create_app()
    return _app


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def client(app):  # pylint: disable=redefined-outer-name
    """Return a session-wide Flask test client."""
    return app.test_client()
```

I am using windows 10, VS Code, Python 3.8.9 and flask-expects-json==1.5.0, redis==3.5.3. The issue happens on all projects on my machine, even though I tried to isolate the issue on different project.

Another point to indicate is like, on the code file there is warning like "Import "flask_expects_json" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports". But at runtime, there are no issues.
What will be the issue with pytest unit tests here? Please help.

Comment: Try running `python -m pytest` instead of `pytest`

Comment: @wim, its giving me " No module named pytest" when running python -m pytest.

Comment: we need more context here as it could be result of many possible causes, can you please share the error log here to make this more clear , are you using a virtualenv? did you try doing a `pip freeze/pip list` to check the installed packages and confirm?

Comment: @philomath - Yes, I am using virtualenv .  I have another clue now which is, when I am using direct python interpreter path to do the "pip install", this error is NOT coming up when using pytest - unit tests execution. Means, if I do package installation 
 " C:\python38\python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt " and then run pytest to run unit tests, this error is coming and everything works fine. Why should I require to specify python interpreter to do pip install to make pytest work correctly